# Long click on a list item in GWT

Tags: list, gwt, mobile, onlongclicklistener

Is there a way in gwt for a long click on a list-item like in a native app for a mobile device.

That is the intuitive click on a smartphone beside the simple click.

I would like to offer a possibility for the user to delete the item.

Something like a longclicklistener...

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
    final Timer longpress = new Timer(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Window.alert("long press!");
        }};

    marker.addMouseDownListener(new Marker.MouseDownHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            longpress.schedule(TIME_LONG_PRESS);

        }
    });

    marker.addMouseUpListener(new Marker.MouseUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            longpress.cancel();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no LongPressListener per se , but you can implement a MouseListener ( http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MouseListener.html ) and onMouseDown , start a timer , cancel it in onMouseUp(). If the timer expires before it is cancelled , then you have a long click.

```
Timer t = new Timer() {
  public void run() {
    //fire long press event.
  }
};
new MouseListener(){

     public void onMouseDown(Widget sender,int x,int y){
         timer.cancel();
        timer.schedule(1000);            
     }

     public void onMouseUp(Widget sender,int x,int y){
        timer.cancel();    
     }
}
```

Comment: Given that `MouseListener` is deprecated for more than 2 years, and that it's probably directed towards touch devices, I'd rather go with the [touch events](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasAllTouchHandlers.html) instead, starting the timer in `onTouchStart` and cancelling it in all 3 other touch events (well, checking for some acceptable position delta in `onTouchMove`)

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that. Yeah the touch events interface is a better way to do it , as it will work on tablets as well.

Comment: GWT 1.5 (the doc you're linking to) is nearly 4 years old. Stick `latest` instead of `1.5` in your URL to find the up-to-date version.

Comment: thanks for your answer... can you post a code example like the one with MouseListener  with the Touch events because I have some problems to get it run.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at m-gwt ( its a mobile UI Framework for GWT) and it has different GestureRecognizers.

see: http://www.m-gwt.com